# SilverStripe conditionals in templates

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, silverstripe

I am trying to modify one of my templates so that a certain include is called on all but two Page types.

The code I am using is:

```
<% if ClassName != BusinessPage || ClassName != BusinessSubPage %>
    ... some code here
<% end_if %>
```

This does not work as the if statement passes on all page types and the code in the if statement is triggered.

If I shorten the code to just one page type it gives the expected results on the page type:

```
<% if ClassName != BusinessPage %>
    ... some code here
<% end_if %>
```

Is there some unexpected issue with using `ClassName` as a conditional in an if statement that I need to be aware of that would explain my issues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your if statement logic isn't quite right. What you want is to use `&&` (`AND`) instead of `||` (`OR`):

```
<% if $ClassName != "BusinessPage" && $ClassName != "BusinessSubPage" %>
```

Here is a logic table showing the results of three different class names.

```
$ClassName      | $CN != BusinessPage | $CN != BusinessSubPage | OR    | AND   |
----------------|---------------------|------------------------|-------|-------|
ABC             | true                | true                   | true  | true  |
BusinessPage    | false               | true                   | true  | false |
BusinessSubPage | true                | false                  | true  | false |
```

The `OR` column shows that no matter what the `ClassName` the result is always true. This is why the if statement always passed.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to put the logic in the `Page_Controller`. This makes the templates easier to read when the logic gets complicated.

**Page.php**

```
public function BusinessTemplate() {
  return in_array($this->ClassName, array('BusinessPage', 'BusinessSubPage'));
}
```

**Page.ss**

```
<% if not $BusinessTemplate %>
  enter code here
<% end_if %>
```